# Fano $3$-folds with one singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a classification of complex Fano $3$-folds, with Picard rank $1$ and a single cyclic quotient singularity of type $\frac{1}{2}(1,1,1)$?

This should be a bounded family by a result of Borisov.

Comment: I'm not sure if a nice clean statement exists, but this paper of Takagi at least covers some of the classification you hope for https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1114649295

Comment: Is it a fact that such Fano 3-folds are not smoothable?

Comment: Yes, they are not smoothable. Indeed the singularity 1/2(1,1,1) is rigid (i.e. it doesn't deform) - see Schlessinger's "Rigidity of quotient singularities", Invent. math., vol. 14, pages 17-26 (1971).